# Relation between eigenvector and image of linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let  $\phi$ be the linear transformation from vector space V to itself. (dimV = n)

By choosing certain basis set, I can write it as a matrix form, say M

Then I want to know that

If {$v_1$,...$v_p$} is the set of eigenvector of M with non-zero eigenvalues,

can I say that 'this set is the basis of the image of linear transformation $\phi$.'

Comment: Counterexample: The sum of the eigenspaces not corresponding to the zero eigenvalue of this matrix: $A=\pmatrix{1 & 2 &1 \\ 0&  1 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0}$ is $\operatorname{span}\pmatrix{1 \\ 0 \\ 0}$.  But that's not the image of the transformation $T(x) = Ax$.

Comment: No problem. :-)

Comment: Any defective invertible matrix is a counterexample.